# fstream just wont create file

Tags: c++, filehandle

Hi I'm trying to use a fstream file handle doing following:

- write to file
- read from file
- create file(if not existing)

the problem:
For some reason I am not able to make it creating the file.

```
filepath= name + "/mails.txt";
mkdir(name.c_str(),0600);
log.open(filepath.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate);
if(!log.is_open())cout<<"error"<<endl;
log<<flush;
```

if the file exists its doing his job but when the file does not exist it wont.

edit: because i badly failed to poste the code in a comment i try it here :D

```
user::user(string aaa)
{
string filepath;
name=aaa;
filepath= name + "/mails.txt";
mkdir(name.c_str(),0666);


//toch("mails.txt",0600);
log.open(name.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate);
if(!log.is_open()){
    log.close();
    log.open(name.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::trunc);
}
if(!log.is_open())cout<<"error"<<endl;
log<<flush;
cout<<"message written"<<endl;
}
```

if there is a system commant like mkdir for creating the .txt it would help too i think

Answer (score 2):

Fstream cannot create a file when using the `ios::in`. It can only open existing files. 
What you should do, is first, check if it opens a file. If it does not, close it, clear its state, and open with `ios::out` - this will create the file.

EDIT:

You can create a file using `ios::in` if you specify `ios::trunc`. However, if the file exists, then you will be deleting all its contents.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you paste your code?

Comment: user::user(string aaa)
    {
    string filepath;
    name=aaa;
    filepath= name + "/mails.txt";
    mkdir(name.c_str(),0666);


    //toch("mails.txt",0600);
    log.open(name.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::ate);
    if(!log.is_open()){
        log.close();
        log.open(name.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::trunc);
    }
    if(!log.is_open())cout<<"error"<<endl;
    log<<flush;
    cout<<"message written"<<endl;
    }

Comment: instead of `log.open(name.c_str()` try using `log.open(filepath.c_str()`
Otherwise the code is fine - it creates a new file for me.